# Fixed size web page gets centered on height on iPhone

Tags: iphone, html, css

I am adapting a fixed size website (800x600 pixels) to work on mobile phones and I have run in to some problems on the iPhone.

I have set the meta viewport tag with width=800 to fit the page exactly on the screen.

Unfortunately on the iPhone it centers the page on the height giving it an unwanted top-margin. It works fine on Android.

How can I get it to align to the top on iPhone?

Here is a simplified version of the page

```
<html>
<header>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=800">
</header>
<body>
  <div style="width:800px; height: 600px;">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add `body { padding: 0; margin: 0; }`

Comment: Already tried that and it doesn't help :(

Comment: Try to add this `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">`. I know this is not what you are asking, but maybe it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this , and it should rescale automatically

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```